# How to redirect to search result page?

Tags: search

I’ve activated the search form block on my Drupal home page.

When a user enters a keyword and presses search button, I would like to redirect to the search page result.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "validate button"? What sort of redirection do you need, as submitting the search form will automatically direct the user to the search results page.

Answer (score 1):

```
function MyModuleName_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
   if ($form_id == 'search_form_id') {
     $form['#submit'][] = 'MyModuleName_custom_serch_form_submit';
   }  
} 

function MyModuleName_custom_serch_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
  if(isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q']))
  {    
     $string_serch= $_GET['q'];
    drupal_goto("http://yourdomain.com/search?q=".$string_serch);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect search result by using `hook_search_box_form_submit`

```
function mytheme_search_box_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   $form_state['#redirect'] = 'path of redirect';
}
```